# JAX WS - Multiple endpoints in single implementation

Tags: interface, jax-ws, endpoint

Not sure if I'm trying to implement something which is incorrect

I have a requirement where webservice methods needs to be separated into different interfaces (multiple interfaces can have same methods). There will be only one implementation for all the interfaces.

So, basically, multiple endpoints for an implementation. Is this possible at all? Can someone provide me with sample code to achieve this please..

Thanks.